# Can login but can't pass other requests using "requests" module

Tags: python, html, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I am trying to automate a function on a site. I'm not sure why but I am able to login, yet unable to pass any requests you'd need to be logged in for. If any extra info is required I will be happy to post it.

1. [/session](https://pastebin.com/uHRrJ1ix)
2. [/users/check-username-availability](https://pastebin.com/UHtyiLC9)
3. [/store/cart?add=1](https://pastebin.com/Q40yhGb5)

```
import requests as req

username = 'username'
password = 'password'
name = 'name1234'

def hd(_token, _site):
    return {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0',
        'X-CSRF-Token': _token,
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Origin': 'https://osu.ppy.sh',
        'Referer': _site,
        'Host': 'osu.ppy.sh'
    }

with req.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/')
    token = r.cookies.get_dict()['XSRF-TOKEN']

    site = 'https://osu.ppy.sh/session'
    r1 = s.post(site, data={
        '_token': token,
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }, headers=hd(token,site))
    print(r1.status_code, r1.reason)

    site = 'https://osu.ppy.sh/users/check-username-availability'
    r2 = s.post(site, data={'username': name}, headers=hd(token,site))
    print(r2.status_code, r2.reason, r2.text)

    site = 'https://osu.ppy.sh/store/cart?add=1'
    r3 = s.post(site, data={
        '_token':token,
        'item[product_id]':'32',
        'item[quantity]':'1',
        'item[cost]':'0',
        'item[extra_info]':name}, headers=hd(token, site))
    print(r3.status_code, r3.reason, r3.text)
```

```
output:
200 OK
403 Forbidden {"error":"Reload page and try again"}
403 Forbidden {"error":"Reload page and try again"}
```

Answer (score -2):

A possible CAPTCHA. As of now osu does have a CAPTCHA and you have to find a way to bypass it.

Comment: that could be so, I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong though. I added some info about the requests, please check them out.